# In Flex, how do I know when the properties of a dynamic object change?

Tags: apache-flex, events, dynamic-class

I have a dynamic class that serves as a storage container for configuration settings. The settings are variables of that class and it has methods to read from and write to a configuration file, database etc. Now I want to trigger writing to the persistant storage whenever a class variable is changed. As the variables are added dynamically at runtime, I can't use get/set methods, also, if I could, that would lead to a lot of boilerplate code.

How can I have an event triggered for changing properties of my class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass this class of yours from [`mx.utils.Proxy`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/utils/Proxy.html). It allows you to have the object be dynamic yet still be able to write some custom code that runs whenever properties are accessed (similarly to getters and setters -- see [`getProperty()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/utils/Proxy.html#getProperty()) and [`setProperty()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/utils/Proxy.html#setProperty()).)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider avoiding the dynamic object, and rather create the data storage class (SettingsModel?) with one method for storing and one method for retrieving data. So instead of using:

```
configurationSettings.randomSetting = value;
```

...you would write:

```
configurationSettings.store("randomSetting", value);
```

You could store the named settings internally in a Dictionary, and do whatever magic needs to be done in the `store()` method.

The main advantage here is readability: when you see a method being called, you know there's functionality behind it. For the same reason I tend to dislike getter/setter functions.

In the end it is a matter of taste, so if your code isn't broken, why fix it. :)